# Query sql with two table in one and show the counting the total number

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table named "star" with has two columns celeb, movie and an other table named "releases" with two columns celeb, album. I want to create a query that will show me a table with tree new columns: celeb, number of albums, number of movies.

So the idea is that I want to show the celeb that have played to a movie (from star table) and also have made an album (from releases table) and below the number of movies and albums.

Thank you

Comment: How do the two "number of albums" columns differ?

Comment: its movies i just edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT movie.celeb, movieCount, albumCount 
FROM 
  (SELECT celeb, count(1) movieCount 
   FROM star GROUP BY celeb) movie INNER JOIN
  (SELECT celeb, count(1) albumCount 
   FROM releases GROUP BY celeb) album ON movie.celeb=album.celeb
```

Comment: IT SHOWS ALL THE LIST OF THE CELEBS IN FACT I WANTED ONLY THOSE WHO HAVE PLAYED IN A MOVIE AND AT THE SAME TIME HAVE MADE AN ALBUM. THANK YOU HOWEVER

Comment: Ok, I modified it so it will only show those with records in both tables, using `INNER JOIN` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant "number of albums" and "number of movies". If that is correct, this should work:

```
select celeb,
       sum(case when num_type = 'movie' then num_recs else 0 end as num_movies,
       sum(case when num_type = 'album' then num_recs else 0 end as num_albums
  from (select celeb, count(*) as num_recs, 'movie' as num_type
          from star
         group by celeb
        union
        select celeb, count(*) as num_recs, 'album' as num_type
          from releases
         group by celeb) x
group by celeb
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select s.celeb, count(distinct movie), count(distinct album)
from star s join releases r on r.celeb = s.celeb
group by s.celeb
```